# Grails searchable plugin installation error

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-searchable

I am using grails 2.2.1 and trying to install the searchable plugin version 0.6.4.

I've added a named proxy and it is set. This seems to be not the problem.

I've changed the buildConfig.groovy as follows:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
```

and the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
     compile ":searchable:0.6.4"
     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
}
```

When compiling I got the following error

```
| Downloading: searchable-0.6.4.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: #searchable;0.6.4: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module
descriptor file found in 'http://grails.org/plugins/grails-searchable/tags/RELEASE_0_6_4/searchable-0.6.4.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins';

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
            grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-searchable/tags/RELEASE_0_6_4/searchable-0.6.4.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

| Downloading: searchable-0.6.4.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

and so on.

Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in Plugins block. Right now its in dependencies.

```
    dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

    }

    plugins {
         compile ":searchable:0.6.4"
    }
```